# AHK random function question, how to randomise what order functions are called

Tags: autohotkey

I was wondering if it is possible to run a line of code that will then randomize between a set amount of other lines, for example;

1::
(i want this function to randomly pick between 2-5 and run that line)

2::`enter code here`

3::`enter code here`

4::`enter code here`

5::`enter code here`

Answer (score 0):

**This looks like a job for AHK [Labels](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Labels.htm):**

Instead of traveling to specific lines, it would be more optimal to save that code inside of different Labels. In order to determine the randomness, use the AHK's [Random](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Random.htm) function to randomly generate a number. Then, use a switch statement to determine which of the previously coded labels you want to go to and run.

**Code:**

```
;Generate a random number from 1 to 5 inclusive
Random, rand, 1, 5

;Use a switch statement to go to the corresponding label
Switch rand{
case 1:goto, One
case 2:goto, Two
case 3:goto, Three
case 4:goto, Four
case 5:goto, Five
}

return

One:
MsgBox This is label "One"
;Insert code in between the colon and the return
return
Two:
MsgBox This is label "Two"
;Insert code in between the colon and the return
return
Three:
MsgBox This is label "Three"
;Insert code in between the colon and the return
return
Four:
MsgBox This is label "Four"
;Insert code in between the colon and the return
return
Five:
MsgBox This is label "Five"
;Insert code in between the colon and the return
return
```

Comment: I have 0 experience with labels so couldnt get that working unfortunetly. However i did find another way i think could work,
something like this:
Tab::
   Random Num, 1, 3
   if (Num=1) {
      ;random code
   }
   else {
      if (Num=2)
         ;random code
   }
return

The problem i ran into now is that when i try to add a else if for the number 3 it gives me an error, what would be the proper way to insert another else if for the number 3?

Comment: 1. I think I already wrote all of the label code for you, just add the code you want randomly run wherever I put a `;Insert code in between the colon and the return` in the code. In any case, if you want more explanation, see [this](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Goto.htm) 2. That if statement chain that you are mentioning is being simplified with a single (Switch)[https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Switch.htm] statement (a switch statement selects one of many code blocks to be executed based on the value of a variable, in this case `rand`, our RNG variable). @tremendousrepeat